# wowza webrtc preview 4.5.0.03 samples, java: package ..plugin.webrtc.model not found

Tags: java, webrtc, wowza

I am trying to compile the test jar for the latest wowza webrtc preview, using the HTTPWebRTCExchangeSessionInfo.java file from the WebRTC_4.5.0.03_updates.zip

When using the files supplied in the /lib folder as global libraries I am getting this message,

java: package `com.wowza.wms.plugin.webrtc.model` does not exist

in reference to `WebRTCCommandRequest` from

```
WebRTCCommandRequest commandRequest = null;
```

I do have `wms-webrtc.jar` added as library, but not sure if this is the correct .jar I need.

Searching https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems and for `com.wowza.wms.plugin.webrtc` yeailds no obvious results.

Any help or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a typo in the wowza example.

Changing `com.wowza.wms.plugin.webrtc.model` to `com.wowza.wms.webrtc.model` fixed this issue immediately. It was only by referencing older code that we noted this include had changed in the wowza source examples.

Answer (score 0):

That jar file is the one that contains that package. It sounds like a corrupted library or a file permission issue. The WebRTC classes should be built-into the installed Wowza libraries, and you should not need to download it separately from the Wowza GitHub page.

1. Try installing a fresh Wowza install on a test server, and update it with the latest build.
2. Download the WebRTC.zip file from the Wowza site again to ensure you have the latest version of the java file.
3. Compile your java file against this new version.